# How to make a grid of the size a rows x b columns from a list containing exactly a*b items? Python grid, list, matrix?

Tags: python, list, matrix, grid, field

How do I make a 3x5 grid out of a list containing 15 items/strings?
I have a list containing 15 symbols but it could very well also just be a list such as mylist = list(range(15)), that I want to portray in a grid with 3 rows and columns. How does that work without importing another module?

I've been playing around with the for loop a bit to try and find a way but it's not very intuitive yet so I've been printing long lines of 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 etc I do apologize for this 'dumb' question but I'm an absolute beginner as you can tell and I don't know how to move forward with this simple problem
This is what I was expecting for an output, as I want to slowly work my way up to making a playing field or a tictactoe game but I want to understand portraying grids, lists etc as best as possible first
1  2  3  4  5
6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15

Answer (score 0):

A `mxn` Grid? There are multiple ways to do it. Print for every n elements.

```
mylist = list(range(15))

n = 5
chunks = (mylist[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(mylist), n))
for chunk in chunks:
    print(*chunk)
```

Gives `3x5`

```
0  1   2 3  4
5  6   7 8  9
10 11 12 13 14
```

Method 2

If you want more cosmetic then you can try

[Ref](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PrettyTable)

```
pip install tabulate
```

Code

```
mylist = list(range(15))

wrap = [mylist[x:x+5] for x in range(0, len(mylist),5)]

from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(wrap))
```

Gives #

```
--  --  --  --  --
 0   1   2   3   4
 5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14
--  --  --  --  --
```

Comment: yesss thanks so much this is what I was looking for! Is there a way to now access the elements still? since as I undrstand, it's not a list anymore, could I access the number 12 or 13 somehow?

Comment: It's much more easier to access elements in list rather than output...So try to access the elemnts in list by index. This wont chnage anything as we are printing grids from lists